# Are there any default values for registers?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand a little code:

```
jg 0x00000047
dec esp
inc esi
add [ecx],eax
```

What is the value of **eax**? These are the four first sentences of the program and i don't know if there is a default value or if the previous sentences add something to eax.

My OS is Linux and the executable is compiled by gcc4.3 from a C source code (gcc file.c exec)

Comment: If you provide some info about your platform (OS, executable format) I'm sure someone can tell you what `eax` is set to at program entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some instructions implicitly update the registers, even if the destinations aren't listed explicitly in the code.  Some examples:

- `cpuid` returns values in eax, ebx, ecx and edx
- `loop` decrements ecx
- `rep` string instructions change ecx, edi and esi
- `rdmsr` changes eax and edx
- `mul` and `div` change eax and edx

And there are many other examples.

You can't assume just by seeing that eax isn't listed in the code that it's not changed.

Even assuming you know which registers are affected by which instructions, the only times you have any guarantee for a value are:

- after an instruction that you know updates it
- immediately after hardware reset

At any other time, you can never make assumptions on the values.

Comment: So we would say that eax has a random(at least random for me) value?

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the platform, language, and/or calling convention.  But yeah, the code before this normally should have set EAX to some value.  EAX is one of those registers that's modified so often that it's not normally used for keeping stuff around in.

The instructions look kinda random.  In particular, the "dec esp" is normally a huge no-no, as the stack should always be dword-aligned.  Are you sure this is actual code?  The instruction bytes translate to "\x7fELF" if i'm translating right, which suggests to me that this is just the header bytes of a Linux program, not actual code bytes.

Comment: I disassembled a little program code written by me in C trying to understand the asm code, i suppose that they are not random instructions. As i say there are no previous sentences, so eax might have a random value. Thank you.

Comment: How are you disassembling the code?  Keep in mind that an executable is rarely just raw code.  (The only format i know of that is is .com files, and those have been obsolete for like 10+ years.)  There's a whole kinda complex format to executables in most 32-bit OSes.

Comment: if x86dis knows how to disassemble an ELF program, maybe.  But it's kinda looking like it's not that smart.

Comment: So that's my problem now, thank you. I'll try to disassemble It better.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are really asking about is [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), which describes how subroutines in a program pass information to one another, and how the operating system passes information to the program, and in general what the different registers are supposed to mean.

For example, the [cdecl calling convention on the x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), which is used by most C compilers, says that when a function returns, the return value value goes on the eax register. So if you have a function `int foo()`, you know that after `foo` executes its [`ret`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Convention_Examples) opcode, eax will contain that int that `foo` returned.

By contrast, the PowerPC processor (usually) has (at least) 32 registers, simply named r0, r1, ... r31. [The AIX calling convention](http://wall.riscom.net/books/proc/ppc/cwg/a_abi.html) for this chip says that the stack pointer goes on r1, that function parameters get passed on r3 through r11, that return values come back on r3, and so on.

It is important to remember that a calling convention is sort of like an agreement between the functions in a program, or between libraries. It isn't part of the hardware, or a law, and there are usually many different calling conventions that may be used on a platform. This is why sometimes you will see code like

```
struct CFoo {  void __stdcall method(); };
```

That is an instruction to MSVC, which usually likes to use the [fastcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx) convention, telling it to use a different convention for that one function. This is important if *eg* the function is defined in a library that was built by some other compiler which uses [stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) instead.

When we talk about how the operating system passes information to a program (or the hardware to the operating system), we usually call it an [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) instead of a calling convention, but it is the same idea. So in the case of your program, it was written assuming that the OS would pass it some particular piece of information on eax. That assumption would be particular to the operating system, the compiler, and possibly even the individual program.

Comment: Thank you very much, this gives me a nice point to understand ASM.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be valid code. Are you sure it wasn't text?

Decoding it as 32bit  x86 gives string `ELF` :

```
00: 7F 45  // 0x7F E
02: 4C     // L
03: 46     // F
04: 01 01  // ?? ??
```

Try opening the file as ELF file and not as just binary.